# Trying to extract key value from parsed JSON in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, twitter

I’m trying to parse some JSON from the twitter API and extract the value of a key (“media_url”), which is a sub-key of the key (“entities”)

so far I have:

```
url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&screen_name=print_broadcast&count=1'
response = RestClient.get(url)
data=response.body
result = JSON.parse(data)
```

How would I extract a key value from the parsed JSON?
I’ve tried

```
result[“entities”]
```

etc, but I get en error when trying to convert a string to integer... the result of my parsed JSON is an array - shouldn't this be a hash?

Sorry for the dumb questions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON output is actually a list. Granted, it only has one element, but it's still a list.

First get `result[0]`, then you can access `['entries']`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I now have a hash to work with: 

`result = JSON.parse(data)   `
`tweet_data = result[0]    `

but I can’t seem to access the key values by name:    

`puts("*** OK ***") if tweet_data.has_key?(‘name’)`     still outputs nothing.

Think I’m missing something obvious - any suggestions? – Steph_1001

Comment: @Steph_1001 - have you tried printing out what `tweet_data` *is*?

Comment: @Steph_1001 - note, too, that the `name` key is under `user` key. If we first assign `tweet_user = tweet_data['user']`, we can then call `tweet_user['name']` :)

Comment: Finally got this cracked with your help, Thanks again.
Turns out there were hashes within arrays within hashes (etc.).
If anyone is wondering, the magic line to extract the image url from a twitter post is `result[0]['entities']['media'][0]['media_url’]`  where `result` is your parsed JSON